# How do you tell the distance to an object based on size alone?

Tags: geometry

For example, say I know an object is 2 meters tall but it appears to be just 0.1 meters tall in my vision. How would I tell how far away it is? What if instead of knowing that it appears to be 0.1 meters tall all I knew was that it took up 10 degrees of my 90 degree wide field of view?

Comment: Have you studied Trignometry? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

Comment: There is no meaning to 0.1 meters tall - it is always a angle of view!